# new account for GMail only

Tags: google-play-store, gmail, google-account, accounts

I added a second account in the GMail aplication, in order to be able to send/receive mail using that account.

I realized that the account has been added not only for GMail, but the Market (Play Store) also sees both accounts now.

Is there a way to keep the second account only in GMail?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this because:

- There's only one Google Services Framework running for all accounts.
- Google Accounts credentials are stored centrally from where Google Apps authenticate.

But, there's a way to solve your issue: Turn on IMAP from Gmail settings. And, use IMAP in default Email app or K-9 Mail app. Done!
Play Store can't see it..

Comment: After much testing of different apps, I find the best solution is to use the free BlueMail app.  This allows me to add e-mail accounts to check (Gmail and others), without needing to add the accounts "globally" to the device.  For example, an extra Google account being used for "e-mail only" won't show up in the Google Play app.  Also, it supports new authentication methods like OAuth2, is user friendly and has e-mail support.